# Error while unpacking the zip from zip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I have the following file structure:

```
yyyy.zip
12x MM-yyyy.zip

each of MM-yyyy.zip
            28-31x yyyyMMdd.prn
```

prn in this case is something like txt.

I have a path to a month and extracting MM-yyyy.zip works great.
Unfortunately, unpacking function for yyyy.zip do not want to iterate through MM-yyyy.zip and unpack them. (Error is below)

The working for the MM-yyyy.zip

```
private static Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> UnZipToMemory(string url)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(url))))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
        {
            MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();
            e.Extract(data);
            result.Add(e.FileName, data);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This function is not working for yyyy.zip

```
private static Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> UnZipToMemoryYear(string url)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(url))))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
        {
            MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();
            e.Extract(data);
            using (ZipFile zi = ZipFile.Read(data))     //error is from this line
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry f in zi)
                {
                    MemoryStream data2 = new MemoryStream();
                    f.Extract(data2);
                    result.Add(f.FileName, data2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thrown error ():

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Ionic.Zip.BadReadException' occurred in Ionic.Zip.dll

Additional information: Could not read block - no data! (position 0x00000000)
```

Some data for your testing (07-2013.zip does not exist in the directory)
If you want all possible files, look at this (http://bossa.pl/index.jsp?layout=mstock&page=1&news_cat_id=706&dirpath=/metastock/mstock/sesjaall)

```
    //string url = "http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/mstock/sesjaall/07-2014.zip";
    string url = "http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/mstock/sesjaall/2013.zip";
    //DownloadZipTest(url);
    DownloadZipTestYear(url);
```

And functions

```
private void DownloadZipTest(string url)
{

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MemoryStream> x in UnZipToMemory(url))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Value.ToArray()));
    }
}

private void DownloadZipTestYear(string urlYear)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MemoryStream> x in UnZipToMemoryYear(urlYear))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Value.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

On dotNetZip 1.9.3 and 1.9 errors are equeal.

Comment: You need to set the position back to 0 after writing to it.

Comment: I found it. Thx for help.  `data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before line with error.